# Is there a docking station product that allows iPad 3 to access internet via an Ethernet connection instead of wireless?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, airport, lightning

I have an iPad 3 which I love but sometimes the Wi-Fi cuts out whilst listening to the radio.  I would like to plug in the iPad to a cradle or docking station which itself has an Ethernet port and so can draw internet directly.

Does anyone know of such a product?
I guess it needs a mini operating system instead of being just an electrical plug

Please don't answer with Bluetooth or other wireless technologies, one problem I have is use in the kitchen and when microwave is working there is a definite drop off in Bluetooth and Wi-Fi capability.  I really need a wired solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I bought an Apple TV.  I solved signal problems in my kitchen by using a Internet over electric mains solution.